# Operational Amplifier

Tags: electrical-engineering, electrical

[image: opamp]

In this case, can I say that $V_E$ correspond to -0.7? if yes, why can this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simplistic explanation Bipolar Junction Transistor is made of two diodes back to back.

[image]

The minimum voltage required switch on the diode between Base and Emitter is 0.7V. Since  $V_B$ = 0V, in order for the diode to be on the voltage across $V_{BE}$ has to be -0.7V.

I hope this helps.

**References:**

- [Bipolar Transistor](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_1.html)